Question regarding proof of a theorem by Riesz in Measure Theory
I have read the following result regarding a sequence of functions in some measure space $(X, \mathscr{A}, \mu)$, and am struggling to understand the neccessity of the introduction of a subsequence rather than the given sequence itself:
Let $\{f_n: X \to \mathbb{R}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converge to $f$ in measure. Then there is a subsequence $\{f_{n_k}\}$
which converges pointwise to $f$ $\mu$-a.e.
The proof is that for each $\delta_k = \frac{1}{k}$, we have some $N_k$ for which $\mu(\{x \in X : |f_{N_k}(x) - f(x)| \geq \delta_k\}) \leq \frac{1}{2^k}$. Letting $E_k = \{x \in X : |f_{N_k}(x) - f(x)| \geq \delta_k\}$, we have that  $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(E_k) \leq 1$. Therefore, it must be that $\limsup E_k$ is null (otherwise $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{N}}\mu(E_k)$ may be arbitrarily large). As a consequence, for all $x \in X \setminus E$, $x$ appears in only finitely many $E_k$, meaning that for all $x$, there is some $K(x)$, so that $k > K$ implies we have that $|f_{N_k}(x) - f(x)| < \delta_k$. Therefore $f_{N_k}$ converges to $f$ for all $x \in X\setminus E$, where $E$ is null, satisfying the definition of $\mu$-a.e. convergence.
I am satisfied with proof from the standpoint that it is convincing, but I do not understand the subtlety in requiring a subsequence. By definition of convergence in measure, we can find $N_k'$ such that all $n > N_k'$ satisfy the condition $\mu(\{x \in X : |f_{n}(x) - f(x)| \geq \delta_k\}) \leq \frac{1}{2^k}$.If these $N_k'$ replace $N_k$ in the original proof then I don't see why it couldn't be said that $\{f_n\}$ converges pointwise to $f$ $\mu$-a.e. The only significance of the $N_k'$ at that point would be that they act as predetermined indexes to offer for arbitarily small $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ needed to show that for appropriately large $n$, the function $f_n$ differs from $f$ by $\delta$ or more in a set of arbitrarily small measure.

I think the issue is that the place where convergence takes place for convergence in measure is not necessarily uniform.
In particular consider the standard counterexample to show that convergence in measure does not imply pointwise convergence: The characteristic functions on sequence of intervals $[0,1], [0,\frac{1}{2}], [\frac{1}{2},1], [0, \frac{1}{3}]$ and so on. Here we have convergence in measure to the function 0, however the place that is not $\delta_k$ (referring to the argument on the last paragraph) away from 0 is constantly changing. Thus we don't necessarily have pointwise convergence.
However, observing that if I consider the subsequence $[0,1] , [0,\frac{1}{2}], [0, \frac{1}{3}]$ and so on, pointwise convergence actually does occur. So the solution to fix the above problem is in fact to choose a sparse enough subsequence.

Thank you for the counterexample. I see now that because $N_k$ is a function of $x$, it can be that the relevant set achieves arbitrarily small measure while cumulatively including $x$ from part of the domain which is not at all arbitrarily small with respect to measure. I also think explicitly listing relevant $E_k$ and $N_k$ is helping me understand. For example, given the described sequence of indicators, one can choose indexes for which the interval of size $2^{-k}$ appears at the interval corresponding to the $k$th position for the geometric series with $r = \frac{1}{2}$
